# What is the correct way to decode JWT(id_token)?

Tags: azure, openid, jwt, yahoo-api, outlook-restapi

After referring the [JWT(id_token) decoding docs](https://developer.mobileconnect.io/content/jwt-idtoken)

I'm confused whether the major service providers will follow the same technique...

Microsoft oauth2.0 client in [git project](https://github.com/jasonjoh/php-tutorial) `getUserEmailFromIdToken()` function did not pad the extra `=` signs based on the size eg `$extrapadds = $jwtTokenSize % 4;`

and Yahoo OAuth2.0 [openid id_token docs](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/decode_id_token.html#decode-id-token=) also didn't mention anywhere. not even the **basic string substitutes for "-" and "_" as "+" and "/"**

is it because these service providers(microsoft and yahoo) didn't follow the standards or did they somehow found a way to avoid such scenarios

Please clarify me... and share a code if possible explaining the right way to decode the JWT `id_token`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a base64 decoder on a base64url encoded token (which is what the JWT is), the padding is not really required, just recommended by spec; see [Why does base64 encoding require padding if the input length is not divisible by 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080988/why-does-base64-encoding-requires-padding-if-the-input-length-is-not-divisible-b)

Also: decoder implementations may be able to deal with the padding themselves.

The Yahoo docs are really wrong as base64 encoding is different from base64url encoding and the spec dictates base64url: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-3 Yahoo is not a really OPenID Connect provider (yet) so that may be why it wasn't fixed before [Yahoo Oauth2/OpenIDconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788779/yahoo-oauth2-openidconnect)

Comment: Agreed with Hans. I'm guessing you posted this on the GitHub repo as well :). See my answer there (which echoes Hans): https://github.com/jasonjoh/php-tutorial/issues/6

Comment: @Hans Z. by saying "Yahoo is not a really OPenID Connect provider (yet)", do you still think it is coz your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27789250/5917094) is on Jan 2015 and today is Mar 2016. If you have any references to check if yahoo / microsoft / google is an openid connect provider, please do share it here... It'll be of great help

Comment: @JasonJohnston The Explanation in github clarified me... you could share the same explanation here for future references and it might help someone who has the same doubt

Comment: @Hans Z. I've referred "https://developer.yahoo.com/openid/" and they(yahoo) claim that they support openID. the saying goes like this -> "That's why we are a huge supporter of OpenID" in the second paragraph... Please edit your later part of the answer... It might mislead people...

Comment: that's OpenID 2.0, which is really different from OpenID Connect as also explained in the article that I linked to